# How to display a data table in a JSP page Struts2

Tags: java, database, jsp, struts2, datatable

So I have been reading on this topic for a couple of days now, and every time I think I understand it I get confused again.

So what I have: A MySQL data base, eclipse, tomcat apache, the beginnings of a GUI using STRUTS2

I am setting up a gui for said database and I want to display one of the data tables in my JSP page. So my problem... well I have a lot of problems but initially, I have a form that is I have an action sending me to the JSP page I want to display my table in. I thought I would use another action to connect to the database and obtain all my information, but I'm not sure if that makes sense anymore, should I just use the same action?

Well... here are bits of my code:

Action to get the data:

```
package net.upsmon.struts2.action;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Table extends ActionSupport  {

List tableRows=new ArrayList();
public String execute() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException{
    List tableInfo=new ArrayList();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "user");
    props.setProperty("password", "pass");
    props.setProperty("databaseName", "db"); 
    String dbUrl="jdbc:mysql://db:3306/db";
    String ret = ERROR;
    Connection myCon = null;
    try{
        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        myCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://dburl:3306/mqmonitordb",props);
        String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";
        PreparedStatement ps = myCon.prepareStatement(dbQuery);
        ResultSet result=ps.executeQuery(dbQuery);
        while(result.next()){

            tableInfo.add(result.getString("raisedAlertId"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("alertHostIP"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("portNumber"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("qMgrName"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("alertType"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("alertGroupName"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("alertEntity"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("maintMode"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("alertCreatedTime"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("alertRaisedTime"));
            tableInfo.add(result.getString("alertAckFlag"));
            tableRows.add(tableInfo); 
            tableInfo.clear();
        }
        //request.setAttribute("tableRows",tableRows);


    }catch(SQLException sqe){

    }catch(Exception e){

    }


    return "yay";
}
public List tableRows() {  
    return tableRows();  
}  
public void setTableRows(List tableRows) {  
    this.tableRows = tableRows;  
}

}
```

JSP page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h2>
       Welcome 
   </h2>


   <table>
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th></th>
               <th>column1</th>
               <th>column2</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <s:iterator status="stat" value="tableRows">
            <tr>
                <td><s:property value="#stat.index+1"></s:property></td>
                <td><s:property value="%{column1}"></s:property></td>
                <td><s:property value="%{column2}"></s:property></td>

            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
</table>


<s:form action="logout" method="post" margin="auto">
    <s:submit method="authenticate" key="label.logout" align="center" />
</s:form>
<s:form action="tolevelselector" method="post" margin="auto">
    <s:submit method="authenticate" key="label.levelthree" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be great, thanks....

Comment: I'm not clear on the question. (Unrelated, but I'd *strongly* recommend not doing all that database work in the action.)

Comment: If not in the action where? My main question is, how to either call the action or how to get all the information from withing the JSP page directly.

Comment: In a service object or at the *very* least a utility method. The data should be exposed to the view layer with a publicly-accessible getter method, then iterated over in the JSP. What's the problem?

Comment: Just that I don't really understand how I would go about doing that, I'm pretty new to this stuff

Comment: Have you looked at any of the S2 documentation, tutorials, books, etc? Exposing data to the view layer is pretty straight-forward, e.g., provide a public getter to the list of information and iterate over that property's name in the view. What's the *specific* problem?

Comment: Using JDBC stuff in the actions is better than use it in the JSPs, but Struts2 has an arm tool called interceptors. And you could move that stuff there. Opening a new connection to the DB is time expensive, so you should read the mysql manual how to configure datasource. Also `java.sql` types could be used with the result set to map db columns to java objects. And finally why do you remove everything fetched from the query?